# Array structure in R studio

Tags: arrays, r

I was trying an array but can't run it:

```
> vector1<-c(4,2,1)
> vector2<-c(22,34,76,88,98,65)
> column.names<-c("col1","col2","col3")
> row.names<-c("row1","row2","row3")
> matrix.names<-c("matrix1","matrix2")
> result<-array(c(vector1,vector2),dim=c(4,2,1),dimnames=list(row.names,column.names,matrix.names))
```

> Error in array(c(vector1, vector2), dim = c(4, 2, 1), dimnames = list(row.names,  :    length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array
>   extent

Above is the error I am getting. What am I doing wrong?
Output should be:

```
, ,Matrix1                                 , ,Matrix2
    col1 col2 col3                             col1 col2 col3
row1 4    22   88                          row1 4    22   88
row2 2    34   98                          row2 2    34   98
row3 1    76   65                          row3 1    76   65
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to create an array with 4 rows (see first value of `dims`) but supply only three rownames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you told `R` that you want an `array` which is `4x2x1` (the `dim` argument), i.e. four rows, two columns and "one coordinate in z direction". 
This means you would need four rownames, two column names and one matrix name.

To get your desired output, just change the dimensions of the array:

```
vector1 <- c(4,2,1)
vector2 <- c(22, 34,76,88,98,65)
column.names<-c("col1","col2", "col3")
row.names<-c("row1","row2","row3")
matrix.names<-c("matrix1", "matrix2")
result<-array(c(vector1,vector2), dim = c(3,3,2), dimnames=list(row.names, column.names,matrix.names))

> result
, , matrix1

     col1 col2 col3
row1    4   22   88
row2    2   34   98
row3    1   76   65

, , matrix2

     col1 col2 col3
row1    4   22   88
row2    2   34   98
row3    1   76   65
```

Also note that the input you provide, i.e. `c(vector1,vector2)` is recycled by the array command. This feature is not always desirable.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help.....i got your point.....then what should i do to get that output i mentioned if start fresh?

Comment: just copy the code in my answer (it had a typo before). My output is the same as your desired output :)

Comment: thanks man,,,already changed that value only,,,,working on that only and was stuck and got confused,,,!! :)